# Getting student demographics report with ActiveRecord

Tags: performance, ruby, ruby-on-rails, database

I have two active records `StudentDemographics` and `StudentWeeklyReport` both having `has_many` relation like this:

```
class StudentDemographics < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :student_weekly_reports, :foreign_key => :student_id
end
```

I have to check marks for each student in the last fifth week seminar with the latest one. If the result is `true`, student should be active, else inactive. I have the following code. Here, I am repeating the loop with each date. `@distinct` is an array of dates.

```
def active_learner

  safe = []

  @active = []

  @inactive = []

  @distinct = StudentDemographics.select(:date).map(&:date).uniq.sort

  @students = StudentDemographics.includes(:student_weekly_reports).select("student_id,date")

@distinct.each_with_index  do |date,i|

 if i < 4

     @count = StudentDemographics.where("date <= ?", date).count

     @active[i] = @count

     @inactive[i] = 0

 else

     sum = safe.length

     active = inactive = 0

     (@students - safe).each do |student|

        next if student.date > date

        @stu = student.student_weekly_reports.last(5)

            if @stu.length > 4

                    if @stu[4].golden_eggs > @stu[0].golden_eggs

                      safe << student

                      active += 1

                    else

                      inactive += 1

                    end

            else

                    safe << student

                    active += 1

            end

      end

      @active[i] = active + sum

      @inactive[i] = inactive

 end

end
end
```

The performance is not good. It's taking more than 3 secs of time. My MySQL database has 13600 in the `StudentWeeklyReports` table and 2000 in the `StudentDemographics` table. Can anyone suggest how I can optimize this?

Comment: `StudentDemographics` has a `date` field, but `StudentWeeklyReport` doesn't? I would have expected the opposite to be true. Perhaps you could provide more context about the whole problem you are trying to solve, and what the motivation is.

Comment: @200_success StudentWeeklyReport also has date field...I have edited my post...In first 4 weeks every one is active...from 5th on wards I have to calculate active students based on the last five weeks data along with that week...if the user marks for 5th week is greater than first week we can consider him as active...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest a couple of things:

1. the `for i in 0...@distinct.length` takes your array's length and uses it to construct a range which it turns into an array again. Not necessarily time consuming but unnecessary and hard to read. Ruby gives you [`each_with_index`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerator/each_with_index) which can do it in a nicer, more concise way.
2. **favoring working with IDs** should speed things up because no Active Record objects need to be created and filled and it's quite enough for your calculations. One important tool for that is [`pluck`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck).
3. I also removed several local variables as you only use them for tallies and that's, again, not really necessary. But no real speedup here, either.

**TL;DR**: here's the re-factored version with calculations in ruby.

```
safe_ids = safe.map(&:student_id)
@distinct.each_with_index do |date, i|
  @active[i] = safe_ids.length
  @inactive[i] = 0
  @student_ids = StudentDemographics.where("id not in (?)", safe_ids).where("date <= ?", date).pluck("student_id")
  @student_ids.each do |student_id|
    @stu = StudentWeeklyReport.where(:student_id => student_id).last(5).pluck(:golden_eggs)
    if @stu.length <= 4 || @stu[4] > @stu[0]
      safe << student_id
      @active[i] += 1
    else
      @inactive[i] += 1
    end
  end
end
```

You could also try and have the whole **calculation done by the database**, by using `group_by` and `having` in a fairly complicated but probably very fast query.

But I'll leave it to the astute reader to figure that one out (mainly since I couldn't manage to get it right in time).

Answer (score 0):

Issing a separate SQL query per record almost always leads to a performance problem. You should be able to formulate this code using just one query, and let the database server do all the work. Stop thinking in terms of Ruby code, and develop a good SQL query that returns three columns (date, active_count, inactive_count).

Comment: Alas, such a query might be impossible in MySQL due to the lack of a `RANK()` function, which would be necessary to work on a pair of seminars four weeks apart. It should be possible in, say, PostgreSQL, which does have such a function.